# Delay an evaluation / lazy evaluation in Python

Tags: python, lazy-evaluation, delayed-execution

I want to delay the evaluation of a call to a member function of an instance of a class until this instance actually exists.

Minimum working example:

```
class TestClass:

    def __init__(self, variable_0):
        self.__variable_0 = variable_0

    def get_variable_0(self):
        return self.__variable_0


delayed_evaluation_0 = test_class.get_variable_0()  # What should I change here to delay the evaluation?
test_class = TestClass(3)
print(delayed_evaluation_0.__next__)  # Here, 'delayed_evaluation_0' should be evaluated for the first time.
```

I tried using `lambda`, `yield` and generator parentheses `()` but I can't seem to get this simple example to work.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using `test_class` before its assignment on purpose?

Comment: @Chris Yes. That's why I need to delay it's evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple `lambda` works. When called, the function will fetch `test_class` variable from the current scope, and if it finds it, that will work, like below:

```
delayed_evaluation_0 = lambda : test_class.get_variable_0()
test_class = TestClass(3)
print(delayed_evaluation_0())
```

prints `3`