# Delay an evaluation containing the key word self in Python

Tags: python, lazy-evaluation, delayed-execution

As a follow up question to

[Delay an evaluation / lazy evaluation in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57687709/delay-an-evaluation-lazy-evaluation-in-python)

I would like to delay an evaluation containing the key word `self` in Python.

Minimum working example:

```
class TestClass:

    def __init__(self, variable_0):
        self.__variable_0 = variable_0

    def get_variable_0(self):
        return self.__variable_0

    def test_delayed_evaluation(self, delayed_evaluation):
        print(delayed_evaluation)


delayed_evaluation_0 = lambda: self.get_variable_0()
test_class = TestClass(3)
test_class.test_delayed_evaluation(delayed_evaluation_0)  # Returns <function <lambda> at 0x0000024E49DE66A8>.
test_class.test_delayed_evaluation(delayed_evaluation_0())  # Returns NameError: name 'self' is not defined.
```

I know this piece of code works when I replace `self` with `test_class`, but in the (other) code in the project I am working on, the class instance is not explicitly known, so I can't use that approach.

Why does Python not recognize `self`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly you are trying to achieve (even reading the previous question); it would be good to have a better use-case.

> Why does Python not recognize `self`?

Because it is not defined at the moment it is called; for your code you effectively could make it work with

```py
delayed_evaluation_0 = lambda self: self.get_variable_0()
test_class.test_delayed_evaluation(delayed_evaluation_0(test_class))
```

I suppose what you want to do would be with something like:

```py
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, variable_0):
        self.__variable_0 = variable_0

    def get_variable_0(self):
        return self.__variable_0

    def test_delayed_evaluation(self, delayed_evaluation):
        return getattr(self, delayed_evaluation)()

    def test_delayed_evaluation_with_parameters(self, delayed_evaluation, *args, **kwargs):
        lazy_func = getattr(self, delayed_evaluation)
        return lazy_func(*args, **kwargs)


test_case = TestClass(3)
test_case.test_delayed_evaluation('get_variable_0')
```

You could also want to look at [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#partial-objects) to complement your knowledge on some use-cases which would be better implemented with it than with `lambda`.